# Is there a way to handle a file in GWT without loading it to the server-side?

Tags: java, gwt, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using a third-party library (GWT Uploader), Servlet and another third-party library (Apache Commons Fileupload) to upload and handle files in the server-side of my web-app. But I want to be able to handle file's content without sending it to the server. How can I accomplish that? Do I need another thrid-party library to do so?

Comment: Did you mean I/O operations with JavaScript?

Comment: @PaulVargas Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ClientIO as seen in this site](http://emitrom.com/blog/client-io), might be useful. I've never used it before, but check out the link.

You may also be able to use [lib-gwt-file](https://code.google.com/p/lib-gwt-file/), which is an implementation of the [HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).